# Nginx + CodeIgniter Posting To Controller 500 Error

Tags: codeigniter, nginx

I previously had this website on an Ubuntu/Apache host which has now been moved to a Debian/Nginx host.  When I moved to Nginx it seems the form which used to work no longer works

How the form works is that it's hosted on a Wordpress website which is located at [www.mycompany.com](http://www.mycompany.com). It then posts the data to a controller which is hosted on the same server but using virtual hosts to site1.mycompany.com.

When I post the data, the form just hangs, looking at the console shows

> POST https://site1.mycompany.com/request_form/submit 500 (Internal Server Error)

The CodeIgniter controller is called request_form and the submit function starts like this (to give you an idea)

```
public function submit()
{       
    $return = array('error' => false, 'msg' => '', 'error_data' => array());
    
    $validation_rules = array();
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('serial_no', 'Outdoor Serial No', 'required');
    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('enquiry_type', 'Enquiry Type', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_email', 'Email', 'required');
    if(!empty($this->input->post('txt_email')))
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_email','email','valid_email|callback_email_exist');
    }
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_phone', 'Phone', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txt_address', 'Address', 'required|callback_check_address_for_state');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('check_address_for_state','Address is not valid!');
```

My Nginx Config for site1.mycompany.com is

```
server {

    server_name site1.mycompany.com;
    root /var/www/html/site1.mycompany.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }



    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    }
    }
```

There are no error logs in either /var/logs/nginx nor under CodeIgniter even when full logging is enabled. I have tried a variety of changes to the Nginx config with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with these basic settings. (for easy debug just add `echo "works"; die;` in the home controller and check.)

**In Ngnix**

```
server {
    server_name site1.mycompany.com;

    root /var/www/html/site1.mycompany.com;
    index index.html index.php;

    # set expiration of assets to MAX for caching
    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
            # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

**In Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://site1.mycompany.com/";
$config['index_page']       = "";
$config['uri_protocol']     = "REQUEST_URI";
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the error changes to

`(index):1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://site1.mycompany.com/request_form/submit' from origin 'https://www.mycompany.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Sorry I should also add the website then becomes unavailable with 404 Not Found, and that would be from changing fastcgi_pass to 127.0.0.1:9000